# remove properties form Object if it doesn't exist in Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is the Object I want to use for fetching the data from the db.

```
let productsIdCount = { 
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asf': 54,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asp': 55,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asi': 114,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asm': 22,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asc': 42,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351ase': 29,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asw': 42,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351ass': 19,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asy': 111,
}
```

This is the data which I want to compare with:

```
let pidArray = [ 
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asi',
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asw',
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351ass',
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asp',
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asy',
]
```

So If the pidArray has an id that doesn't exist in productsIdCount, than I want to remove that id property and value pair from the object. 
Or just to create another object and add the prop and value pair that have the same id in the array.

Comment: what do you mean by `an id that doesn't exist in productsIdCount, than I want to remove that id property and value pair from the object` please? not possible to remove something that does not exist...

Comment: e.g. this id "9r854asdsdsdf16351351asc" taken from the object doesn't exist in the array. So I want to remove it from the object with it's value pair '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asc': 42

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop to create the new object:

```
const result = {};
for (const prop in productsIdCount)
    if (pidArray.includes(prop))
        result[prop] = productsIdCount[prop];
```

Comment: Also I want to take the first three elements from the newly created Object. If it's necessary I will update the question.

Comment: @reactive Objects don't have an order, so there is no "first three". Maybe you mean an object with only the first three from `pidArray`? Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that.

Comment: You could do something like `pidArray.slice(3).includes(prop)` if all the `pidArray` values are known to exist. You might want to loop over `pidArray` otherwise and stop when you have found three elements that were properties of the object.

Comment: This is not the case. Then I should sort the object and slice it (like if it was an array). Already found a solution. Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot sort and slice objects. You should just do the iteration the other way round: `let i=0; for (const pid in pidArray) if (pid in productsIdCount) { result[pid] = productsIdCount[pid]; if (++i >= 3) break; }`

Answer (score 0):

try this one out:

```
let productsIdCount = { 
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asf': 54,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asp': 55,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asi': 114,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asm': 22,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asc': 42,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351ase': 29,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asw': 42,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351ass': 19,
    '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asy': 111,
}

let pidArray = [ 
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asi',
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asw',
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351ass',
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asp',
  '9r854asdsdsdf16351351asy',
]

const f = (objValues, listOfPids) => {
  const filteredValue = {};
  for(pid in objValues) 
    if (listOfPids.includes(pid)) 
      filteredValue[pid] = objValues[pid]
  return filteredValue;
}

const newValue = f(productsIdCount, pidArray);

console.log(newValue);
```

[image]

Comment: How do you count the time when the for loop is finished. Offering external links would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @reactive, I used sublime text 3 to run js in node. it comes with a default execution time. :)